# How to specify a maxInMemorySize in MB or GB in Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am relatively new to Java and Spring. I am trying to make an application where user can upload files of sizes up to 2.5 GB. So I have tried setting this in `springapp-servlet.xml` file from what I have read somewhere.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2500001000" />
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="2500001000" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8" />
</bean>
```

However, it gives me following error:

```
"Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' 
 to required type 'int' for property 'maxInMemorySize';"
```

I think this error is because I am a very long value in value. How can I specify this value in MB or GB?

Comment: I have noticed that the error is not thrown in the case of 'maxUploadSize' but only for 'maxInMemorySize' for the same value. Changed question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

maxUploadSize is not String and you pass it a string and in cant convert in to number you have to pass a number like this :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <property name="maxUploadSize">
            <value>100000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

for unlimited value is -1

you just need to change maxUploadSize and uploaded files will still be received past the MaxInMemorySize amount, but they will not be stored in memory.

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't make any difference. I get the same error.

I did read about the -1 option but that will allow the user to upload some random large files which I don't want to happen.

Comment: you have to change maxUploadSize(long) and maxInMemorySize (int) style and then can give them long and int value

Comment: you dont need to set MaxInMemorySize and maxUploadSize as the same, MaxInMemorySize  set the maximum allowed size (in bytes) before uploads are written to disk. Uploaded files will still be received past this amount, but they will not be stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

`setMaxInMemorySize` will call `setSizeThreshold(int sizeThreshold)` in `org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory` and I don't think it could be specify 'MB'. So you may need to use other FileItemFactory or code one youself.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides a class called [DataSize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-conversion-datasize).  If you set up your own configuration class you can use that type instead of "int".  It probably would have been more convenient for you if Spring had used that property type instead.